# How to come out of while loop during debugging

Tags: eclipse

During debugging in Eclipse , my code went into the while loop ( I dont want to loop until the condition is met )

so please tell me how to come out of while loop during debugging ??

And i see that F7 is disabled under Debug Menu

please see the screen shot here

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=wajzeu&s=5

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can select the line that is just outside your while loop in the code editor, then right click and choose **Run to Line** in the context menu (Or simply use the default hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> )

[image]

Comment: can you post the code of the program ? and can the while loop exist if you run the program normally (with debug mode)?

Comment: Yes the code is fine and runs good , and What i did to solve the problem is , i put another  break point after while loop and used F8

Answer (score 0):

Pressing `ctrl+R` is the correct option but if your break point is on a line which is inside the for loop, then you will have to first remove the break point and then press `ctrl+R` on the line on which you want the control to land. I faced this issue while debugging.